# dotnet run hangs in running Docker container

Tags: docker, .net-core

I have an Angular 8 .NET Core application that I'm trying to run in Docker. I can successfully create a Docker image and run a container in detach mode. I'm able to exec into the running container and go into the Angular folder and run `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` successfully. When I go to the .NET folder and run `dotnet run`, it hangs at 'Using launch settings from .../launchsettings.json'. In the Dockerfile I expose port 80 with the line `EXPOSE 80`. When I run the container, I map the ports for both the Angular frontend (4200) and .NET backend (5000) like so:

```
docker run -it --rm -d -p 4200:4200 -p 5000:80 portal /bin/bash
```

I don't receive any errors when I run `dotnet run` in the container. How do I get `dotnet run` to finish?

UPDATE: 
Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /app/
EXPOSE 80

#install node and npm
RUN apt-get update -yq && apt-get upgrade -yq && apt-get install -yq curl git nano
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash - && apt-get install -yq nodejs build-essential

#install angular-cli
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

RUN mkdir library
#add local nuget packages
ADD ./library/. /app/library

RUN mkdir Web
COPY ./Web/. /app/Web
RUN cd Web && npm install

RUN mkdir API

# currently in the app folder
COPY ./API/Api.csproj /app/API
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_NET_HTTP_USESOCKETSHTTPHANDLER=0
COPY ./API/NuGet.config /app/API

RUN cd API && dotnet restore

#copies all files into current directory
COPY ./API/. /app/API
```

Here is my launchsettings.json:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:52121",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "API": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000/"
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE 2:
I found a .NET Core Docker sample app https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-3.1
I added the port 80 profile in the sample app's launchsettings.json to my launchsettings.json with no success. I am completely stumped at this point. I've ran 'dotnet run' with '--verbosity detailed' in the docker container and receive no warnings or errors. I suspect it could be something to do with the database connection, but I don't even know where to begin on how to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Can you show the Dockerfile and launchsettings.json?

Comment: @Kevin I added my Dockerfile and launchsettings.json

Comment: Can you try to change the 'commandName' within the 'API' profile to 'Docker'? Are there any Docker logs available?

Answer (score 2):

My Answer may seem funny to some of you but believe me, this happened to me and I was thinking that `docker run` is stuck but actually it wasn't and the reality was **just nothing was logged incase of successful run by previous developer**
[image]

Its run successfully and nothing is stuck, see another example here:
[image]

Comment: Same issue here. The issue was the logging configuration set to Warning. setting it to information ("Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information" in appsettings) solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

You should add another profile that contains information regarding the Docker settings. As Microsoft mentioned on their website

The default profile information is

```
"Docker": {
  "commandName": "Docker",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://+:443;http://+:80",
    "ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT": "44360"
  },
  "httpPort": 51803,
  "useSSL": true,
  "sslPort": 44360
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-launch-settings?view=vs-2019

Comment: I added the Docker profile you provided above to my launchsetting.json and dotnet run still hangs at 'Using launch settings from ....'

Answer (score -3):

launchSettings.json

```
  "applicationUrl": "http://0.0.0.0:5000/"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Additionally, which applicationURL in the question needs to be replaced with this?